# How to rewrite wordpress search to work on specific category

Tags: functions, categories, url-rewriting, search, htaccess

I want my wordpress search to work on specific category within custom search, by default this actually work fine `example.com/categoryname/?s=keyword`

but I want to make it work like this `example.com/categoryname/search/keyword/`

I have the below code but it only work on the url `example.com/search/keyword`

```
function wp_change_search_url() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/search/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }  
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_change_search_url' );
```

but if i try `example.com/categoryname/search/keyword/` i get 404 error page

Please I need help I want it to work within the category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/):

```
add_action( 'init', function(){
    // Non-paged requests. E.g. example.com/categoryname/search/keyword/
    add_rewrite_rule( '^categoryname/search/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?category=categoryname&s=$matches[1]',
        'top' );

    // For paged requests. E.g. example.com/categoryname/search/keyword/page/2/
    add_rewrite_rule( '^categoryname/search/([^/]+)/page/(\d+)/?$',
        'index.php?category=categoryname&s=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'top' );
} );
```

**Be sure to flush the permalinks — simply visit the Permalink Settings page.**

Comment: It works but is there anyway to replace the /search/ to anything else?

Comment: Sure.. you can use a different slug (e.g. `/find-posts/`) or path (e.g. `/search/posts/`), just make sure to test it and confirm it doesn't conflict with existing permalinks/rules.

Comment: Thanks I have fixed it.